# How to set a custom edit-style icon in a UITableViewCell while in edit mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, editmode

Is there any way to have a custom edit-style icon (besides the green plus and red minus icons) when enabling edit-mode in a `UITableView`?

I know I could simulate the the edit-mode animation and just move the cell contents to the right and add a UIImageView, but I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to customize the editing style of a cell is using [tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:](http://tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:) which must return a UITableViewCellEditingStyle.

None, delete (red minus), and insert (green plus) are the only options. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellEditingStyle):

> **Cell Editing Style**
>
> The editing control
>   used by a cell.
>
> ```
> typedef enum {   
> UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone,   
> UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,   
> UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert  
> } UITableViewCellEditingStyle;
> ```

Comment: By the way — these is a third option called "multi-select" with editingStyle = 3. This is an **undocumented** feature.

Comment: I guess I'll have to resize the cell's subviews myself then.

Comment: Gah, that undocumented option would be perfect for us. Search on the iOS dev forums for uitableview with multi row selection for the official answer on this: don't use. Grrr.

Comment: Check out the _Table View Multi-Row Edit Mode_ blog post from Jeff LaMarche: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/table-view-multi-row-edit-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

You can return as shown in below code

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
if(indexPath.row == 0) 
    {

        return  UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    else
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```